# CORS could not get fixed even after adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin in service

Tags: ajax, rest, cors

I tried to access a Rest service which was hosted in different domain from mine through an ajax call and I got "CORS" error in the firebug.

After researching about this problem, I figured out that the service needs to be changed by adding **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to * in the response header. I did that in the service as well.

```
public Response search(String expression) {

  return Response.ok() //200
    .entity(ConnectionUtils.query(expression))
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type,Accept")
    .allow("OPTIONS").build();

}
```

Above method is the implementation class of below service interface:

```
@POST
@Path("/search")
public Response search(String expression);
```

I tried to post a request to this url through chrome advanced rest client, I am getting the response as well. Also the response header shows that the **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** has been set properly as well. Please refer to below screenshot of chrome client:

[image]

If you see above, the response headers has been changed.

But my below ajax call always return CORS error:

```
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.100:8080/cqs-1.0-SNAPSHOT/services/services/cqs/search. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://192.168.1.100:8080/cqs-1.0-SNAPSHOT/services/services/cqs/search",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"offer.offer.offerId.USSellerId": {$gt: 0}},
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.statusText);
        console.log(data.name);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use CORS.  It's fraught with peril.  Rather, set up a simple reverse proxy on the server using Apache (or similar).  Once you set it up, all requests from your app can go back to your domain/port thus not triggering any OPTION methods from the browser.  Meanwhile your reverse proxy can redirect requests based on the path in the url, which is completely up to you on how you want to configure.

In my case, I just had a simple case of needing to access 2 different ports on the same server.  Port 8080 (tomcat) was serving my GWT UI and REST requests from my GWT pages (using RestyGWT) were needing to hit port 9000 (Play framework port).  Due to the different ports, CORS was required to deal with the OPTION 'preflight' checks that the browser was doing.

To solve this I just setup my URLs as having either /ui path or a /api path.
Since the domain/port was the same, and my proxy could easily redirect transparently to the correct port (api -> 9000 and ui -> 8080)  there was no longer any need for CORS.

CORS has a lot of issues in my experience including cookies.  It's really better to avoid it using a reverse proxy.

If you need more details, I can post more - let me know.

JR